# How to refresh and update refresh token stored in redux store when api gives a 403 status

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, jwt, refresh-token

I have an api configuration which handles all the api calls in the app. When the token expires, the backend gives a 403 status and based on that i need to update the tokens. Here is the code i have:

```
// General api to access data
import ApiConstants from './ApiConstants';
import {store} from '../redux/store';
import * as loginActions from '@/redux/actions/loginActions';

export default function api(path, params, method, extraHeaders) {
  let options = {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      device: 'mobile',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + store.getState()?.authReducer?.token,
      ...extraHeaders,
      // ...(token && {token: token}),
    },
    method: method,
    ...(params && {body: JSON.stringify(params)}),
  };

  return fetch(ApiConstants.BASE_URL + path, options)
    .then(response => {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        response.json().then(responseParsed => {
          if (response.status == 200 || response.status == 201 || response.status == 204) {
            // success
            resolve(responseParsed);
          } else if (response.status == 403) {
            // access token unauthorised
            if (store.getState()?.authReducer?.token) {
              toast.show('Session Expired. Please Login again', {
                type: 'danger',
                position: 'bottom',
                duration: 3000,
                offset: 30,
                animationType: 'zoom-in',
              });
            }
            store.dispatch(loginActions.logOut());
            resolve({status: false, result: responseParsed});
          } else {
            toast.show(responseParsed?.message, {
              type: 'danger',
              position: 'bottom',
              duration: 3000,
              offset: 30,
              animationType: 'zoom-in',
            });
            resolve({status: false, result: responseParsed}); // failed
          }
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // alert('yay')
      console.log('error at utility in function apiCall at catch: ' + err);
      //   showSnackbar('Something went wrong, please check your network.');
      // Snackbar.show({ text: "Something went wrong", duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG });
    });
}
```

How to intercept the call and add the refresh the token logic in this flow?

Comment: You're already doing great I guess, you just need to navigate to the login screen like `navigation.navigate('login')` in `else if (response.status == 403)` condition and pass the credentials so it'll generate your token again.

Comment: when the api gives 403 statuscode i need to refresh the token and then call again the api which gave 403 or else the app flow will be broken, thats where i am stuck! :-(

Comment: If you want to refresh your token you may need to call login API to that condition with the saved credentials of login in the redux store. I don't think it's a good practice, so you can ask to the developer for refresh token API

Comment: yes. there is a refresh token api. With that i can refresh the token, but how to call the already invoked api again as the api gave an error, at first and then token got updated

Comment: pass something in the result statement of `resolve({status: false, result: responseParsed});`, save that to redux states and handle that in `componentDidUpdate` function and play with `prevProps` and updated props, call the refresh token API there.